# Accessing 32-bit DLLs from 64-bit code exe sample

Tags: mfc, com

I want access 32 bit dll from 64 bit code .. can you please provide me sample or idea.

Comment: This question is very wide, please try it to narrow it down :)

Comment: i have 64 bit exe ..i want to access 32 bit dllss

Comment: Well, you're not narrowing it down here, you're repeating it. Maybe try to give more context, code examples of what you'd like to be able to do and so on...

Comment: http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/ i did this but its not wokring

Comment: Are you trying to invoke code in the dll? or merely examine its structure and load assets from it? `LoadLibraryEx` has flags that can allow a process to load a dll from a different architecture, but obviously no code can be executed. The handle should work with the resource loading functions however.

Answer (score 3):

A 64-bit process cannot load 32-bit binaries and vice-versa. If you want to access 32-bit binaries from a 64-bit process, you need to create a 32-bit surrogate process that calls into the 32-bit DLL, and provides some means of [Interprocess Communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx).

The 64-bit process would then issue requests to the 32-bit process, that forwards them to the 32-bit DLL, and report results back to the 64-bit process. You have to work out the details for the communication channel(s) yourself, as your question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think You'll need to have the 32-bit dll loaded into a separate 32-bit process.

This link may help you :

https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Comment: thanks ... any sample code is avaiable